# Add posibility to add biography elements to profile from application

Tags: feature-request, android-app

Add biography elements from stackoverflow application

Comment: If the question is specific to the new Stack Overflow application, it should be move to [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stackoverflow-app).